# Fill Nulls with values in another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. In dataframe1, I have a column with some Null values. I want to fill those null values using the values of another data frame i.e.,dataframe2 by comparing of values of different column of each dataframe.

DataFrame 1:

```
Col1 Col2
A    Null
B    Null
C    NUll
A    1000
B    1120
C    3200
```

Data Frame 2:

```
Col1 Col2
A    500
B    110
C    320
```

Now I want to fill the null values in first dataframe with values from second dataframe where dataframe1.col1 =  dataframe2.col1

The final desired output is like:

```
Col1 Col2
A    500
B    110
C    320
A    1000
B    1120
C    3200
```

How can I do this in Pandas Dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard method is to combine series.replace / series.fillna with series.map(dict).

```
fill_dict = dataframe2.set_index('Col1')['Col2'].to_dict()
dataframe1['Col2'] = dataframe1['Col2'].replace('Null', dataframe1['Col1'].map(fill_dict))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace `NaN`s by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].mask(df1['Col2'] == 'Null')
print (df1)
  Col1  Col2
0    A   NaN
1    A   NaN
2    C   NaN
3    A  1000
4    B  1120
5    C  3200

df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].combine_first(df1['Col1'].map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2']))
#alternative 
#df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].fillna(df1['Col1'].map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2']))

print (df1)
  Col1  Col2
0    A   500
1    B   110
2    C   320
3    A  1000
4    B  1120
5    C  3200
```

**Details**:

```
print(df1['Col1'].map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2']))
0    500
1    500
2    320
3    500
4    110
5    320
Name: Col1, dtype: int64

print(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2'])
Col1
A    500
B    110
C    320
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
```

Another solution is filter by condition values for `map`:

```
m = df1['Col2'] == 'Null'
df1.loc[m, 'Col2'] = df1.loc[m, 'Col1'].map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2'])
print (df1)
  Col1  Col2
0    A   500
1    B   110
2    C   320
3    A  1000
4    B  1120
5    C  3200
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the strings to nan and then combine the dataframes i.e

```
df.assign(Col2 = pd.to_numeric(df.Col2,errors='coerce'))\
     .set_index('Col1').combine_first(df2.set_index('Col1')).reset_index())

   Col1    Col2
0    A   500.0
1    A  1000.0
2    B   110.0
3    B  1120.0
4    C   320.0
5    C  3200.0
```

Comment: Its the sorting issue, you win sir. Since the OP didnt mention the index at the end let the solution stay.